# Grails working with legacy database SQL server

Tags: sql-server, grails, groovy, nullpointerexception, grails-orm

A simple Grails 1.3.7 applications with SQL server 2000.  connection OK.  create new table OK. however, when trying to access existing tables, see error below.  Constraints: cannot change the existing data.  Questions: what file is this error line [35] in?  Is there any way to allow null object (e.g. NOT to get property 'id' when the object is null)?

```
Error 500:
Servlet: default
URI: /root0001/person/list
Exception Message: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
Caused by: Error evaluating expression [personInstance.id] on line [35]: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
Class: /person/list
At Line: [35]
Code Snippet:
Stack Trace

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error evaluating expression [personInstance.id] on line [35]: Cannot get property 'id' on null object

    at person_list$_run_closure2_closure27.doCall(person_list:67)

    at person_list$_run_closure2.doCall(person_list:60)

    at person_list$_run_closure2.doCall(person_list)

    at person_list.run(person_list:76)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object

    at person_list$_run_closure2_closure27_closure34.doCall(person_list:67)

    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Where do you retrieve the `personInstance`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely happening in your list.gsp, in the section that tries to render the personInstance Id. You can use the Groovy [safe dereference operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Null+Object+Pattern) to hack past this, but you may want to investigate why your database is returning a null object for 
the list view.